# Android LinearLayout how to access a cell in a matrix

Tags: android, matrix, android-linearlayout

I am developing a Tic-Tac-Toe game in which the size is N*N and not 3*3, and I am using ImageView to implement the game board.

As a beginning I am trying to implement the board as a matrix in which I will be able to access any cell  because I am adding a single player mode with an AI.

The code that builds the board on the screen in the onCreate method is this:

```
    //defining the board and parameters
    main = new LinearLayout(this);
    main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    main.setLayoutParams(params);
    //implementing the board
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        row.setLayoutParams(params);
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            //drawing empty spaces in the squares, player=1 is for the player and player=2 is for the AI
            player=0;
            MyImageView cell = new MyImageView(this,player); //code that draws on the board using MyImageView - a class that extends ImageView
            Board[j][i]=player;
            cell.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width / k, width / k));
            cell.setOnClickListener(this);
            row.addView(cell);
        }
        main.addView(row);
    }
    setContentView(main);
```

k is the order of the board matrix.

Now, my problem is that I don't know how to access to a certain cell through the MainActivity class and draw a Circle in it, because the player is the X and the AI is the Circle.

I only need help in implementing the board so that I will be able to access any cell on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a coordinate-system and a way to identify the different cells. For instance each cell could get an id like this

```
cell.setId(numCells++);
```

where numCells is set to 0 before the first for-loop.

An other way is maybe to create a grid and store the coordinate in the tag of the cell:

```
cell.setTag(tag)
```

where tag is 
    tag = String.valueOf(j)+"x"+String.valueOf(i)

Or you could store the formentioned ids of the cells in a array-grid and access the right cell based on the position in the grid.

EDIT:

You can access a specific sell by calling :

```
cellToDrawIn = findViewById(AI-prefered cell ID);
```

or

```
cellToDrawIn = findViewByTag(AI-prefered cell TAG);
```

How the get the ids or tags depend on how your AI calculates where it whant to put a circle.

Remeber, this a one of many possible solutions...

And are GridView out of the question?

Comment: Can you explain to me how can I access a certain cell if I only have it's tag or number? I need to access it through the LinearLayout main that I have defined.
P.S. How can I access a certain row in LinearLayout main?

Comment: Yuo can access a cell by using findViewById or findVieByTag. I'v editted my answer.

Comment: what is the type of the varaiable cellToDrawIn? how do I find a specific cell through the LinearLayout variable main?

Comment: CellToDrawIn is just a variable of the same type as cell in your code. with cellToDrawIn = findViewById(id) or findViewbyTag(tag), you get a variable, cellToDrawIn, you can modify in order to change the layout of that specific cell.